# why multiple div with ::before and ::after have single background image in chrome whereas Firefox shows multiple background image?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, pseudo-element

I have code running well in chrome but it acts differently in Firefox. Here i am using multiple div with pseudo-element *::after* and *::before* which take background image as single (many div ≡ one background image) for all div elements while running in chrome web browser.
But in Firefox, individual div elements take each background image (many div ≡ many background image). So how to resolve this issue for Firefox web browser?
The sample Html and css code that i use are:

```js
  $('.container div').mouseover(function(){
           $(this).addClass('flip')
       })
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden; 
    background: green;
    font-size: 0;
}
.container div{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container div:hover{
    z-index: 10000;
}
.container div::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/2/e/6/205615.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg) translateY(0);
    transition: 0.5s linear;
    padding: 1px;
}
.container div.flip::before{
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%);
}
.container div::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://wallpaperhd.wiki/wp-content/uploads/laptop-wallpapers-s26hfq.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(50%);
    transition: 0.5s linear;
    padding: 1px;
}
.container div.flip::after{
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg) translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
   </div>
```

The code for online testing are provide in  https://codepen.io/prakashdude/pen/xxGpjap

Comment: an old known bug related to background-attachement fixed that doesn't work with transformation

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif , you figure out exact issue.